# JW Player won't play the video in Drupal

Tags: drupal, video, video-streaming, jwplayer

I'm trying to fix some issues on a website somebody else did in Drupal. One of them is that the videos that are played with the JW Player plugin are not being played correctly. Only the sound is heard, and there is a visualization where the video should be. Only when the video is paused you can see the still shot of where the playhead is stopped in the video. You can see what I am talking about in this page:
http://www.xxtrusion.tv/xx-trusiontv

Is there an obvious problem I am not seeing? I am pretty new with Drupal, and the project is very urgent. I would be grateful for any help I can get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the Revolt plugin was on :/ Tech support helped me out. Kudos to them.